# How to pass multiple lazyload placeholders to picture element?

Tags: html, responsive-design, lazy-loading, responsive-images

We can implement lazyload into picture element within source tags. But we've got only one img tag and we can load lazyload placeholder image in this img tag's src attribute. So if I want to set seperate lazyload placeholders for each image that is lazyloaded, is there a way to achieve it? I need this because I want to set different picture frames for portable devices and desktops. Let's say one image with a higher height value for portable devices (and will be loaded if the viewport is smaller than 1200px) and the other image with a higher width value for the desktop viewports (1200px or above).
Ex:

```
<picture>
    <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none"><![endif]-->
    <source
            data-srcset="640.jpg 640w,
                990.jpg 990w,
                1024.jpg 1024w"
            media="(max-width: 1024px)" />
    <source
            data-srcset="1200.jpg 1200w" />
<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
<img
        src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
        data-src="1024.jpg"
        class="lazyload"
        alt="image with artdirection" />
</picture>
```

Code is taken from [afarkas.github.io](https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/index.html)

Let's say the image in first source tag has got a width of 640px and a height of 900px and the image in the second source tag's got a size of 1200px width and 900px height. Here I'll need to load different low quality images for portable devices and desktops, but I can set only one img tag, and therefore only one image placeholder in it's src attribute. What can we do to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Emre

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make the picture element intrinsic and then control the picture element via CSS and media queries.

Like this:

```
picture.intrinsic {
display: block;
position: relative;
height: 0;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 100%; // Default to square
}
picture.intrinsic img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

And then add media-queries to .intrinsic that sets different padding-bottoms.